# Cloudant Java SDK v1.0.1 - bulk delete?

Tags: java, cloudant

Is there any efficient way to delete a list of keys from Cloudant? I saw API to insert but not delete.

If I need to delete half of my database, will I see tons of HTTP requests?

Answer (score 0):

do bulk update with the following:
{"_id": "id_of_doc", "_rev": "rev_of_doc", "_deleted": true}

interestingly with this approach, it will update the document, meaning that you will have a brief window (before our compactor runs and cleans up the document and all previous revisions) where you can still retrieve the data of the document prior to the delete by using the old revision.
so there is room to undo deletes for a short period of time.

Comment: Docs for `_bulk_docs` here: https://docs.cloudant.com/document.html#bulk-operations. I'd also note it would be _very_ unwise to rely on the content of previous revisions sticking around for any length of time.